import DocumentPicker from "react-native-document-picker" return error
when run react-native in Edge browser  , return error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getEnforcing') in NativeDocumentPicker.ts
import pickDirectory from "react-native-document-picker";
export async function importDocument(fileType, multiSelect) {
    try {
        console.log("importDocument")
        const doc = await DocumentPicker.pick({
            type: [DocumentPicker.types[fileType]],
            allowMultiSelection: multiSelect
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(`get error ${error} in ImportDocument importDocument`);
    }
}


First of all install latest version of react-native-document-picker and then you can use DocumentPicker like this -
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import DocumentPicker, { types } from "react-native-document-picker";

const handleDocumentSelection = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await DocumentPicker.pick({
      presentationStyle: "fullScreen",
      allowMultiSelection: true,
      type: [types.pdf, types.docx, types.images, types.csv, types.doc],
    });
    setFileResponse(response);
  } catch (err) {
    if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
      // User cancelled
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // throw err;
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}, []);

